# Returning data for the highest total in a group

Tags: sql, select, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have these tables:

- customers, which includes: employee id of the employee that helped them
- orders, which includes: order number, product ID, shipping date, customer name who ordered that item
- orderdetails, which includes order number, quantity, product ID
- employee, which includes first name, last name

How could I show the last name and first name of the employee with the highest quantity of products sold?

I know I have to use multiple joins, aliases, and a few HAVING statements, but I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: Can you confirm that `product` is on `orders`, and not on `order details` - viz, on the `details` table, to what does `quantity` refer, if not a `sku`  / `item` / `product code`?

Comment: I suspect you have set up a duplicate account: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27327810/sql-inner-join-customers-with-orders

Comment: @StuartLC, edited it, and i hope it made it more clear!

Comment: @MitchWheat haha that is actually a fellow group member. we are all working on this project together.

Comment: You mean you are all 'not working on it' but simply sending the problem to SO!

Answer (score 0):

You won't need `HAVING` at all. As you've suggested, join all the tables on the join keys, and then group by both of the employee name columns.

The below query (with derived table) should be agnostic to any RDBMS, but excludes the final consideration of limiting the result to one row only, which is dependent on the RDBMS

```
SELECT d.FirstName, d.LastName, d.TotalQuantity
FROM
(
    SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, SUM(od.Quantity) AS TotalQuantity
    FROM OrderDetails od 
    INNER JOIN Orders o ON OrderDetails.OrderId = o.OrderId
    INNER JOIN Customers c ON o.CustomerName = c.CustomerName -- Switch to a surrogate key
    INNER JOIN Employees e ON c.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId 
    -- WHERE od.ProductId = `FooBars` -- If you need a filter
    GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName
) d
ORDER BY d.TotalQuantity DESC;
```

For the 'just the top employee' requirement, you'll need to limit the row count to just 1, which is RDBMS dependent:

- Change last line to `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1;` for MySql
- or Change last line to `ORDER BY ... FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY;` for newer versions of SqlServer and Oracle
- or Change first line to `SELECT top 1 d.FirstName, ..` for older versions of SqlServer

Notes:

- As per the comment, it seems strange that the product id is on the Orders table, sku / item code would typically be at the order item level
- Modelling the serving employee id directly on the customer table isn't a good idea - what about repeat customers? A new `ServingEmployeeCustomer` junction table sounds in order.
- Joining on CustomerName is also not a great idea - if there is no natural key, recommend generating a simple surrogate key (INT identity / auto number, or a Guid, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT e.FirstName, e.LastName, SUM(od.Quantity) AS Quantity
FROM OrderDetails od 
INNER JOIN Orders o ON od.OrderId = o.OrderId
INNER JOIN Customers c ON o.CustomerName = c.CustomerName 
INNER JOIN Employees e ON c.EmployeeId = e.EmployeeId 
GROUP BY e.FirstName, e.LastName
ORDER BY Quantity DESC;
```